# Issue with searching for object property in array for JSON data type

Tags: mysql, jsonpath, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I have the following schema with `value` as JSON type

```
mysql> select * from people;
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | value                                                                     |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| blah | {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}                                      |
| foo  | {"key1": "value1", "friends": [{"friendId": "123"}, {"friendId": "foo"}]} |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expected the query below to return me row `foo` but it did not.

```
mysql> select * from people where value->'$.friends[*].friendId' = "123";
Empty set
```

The condition `value->'$.friends[*].friendId'` seems valid since it works for the query below:

```
mysql> select value->'$.friends[*].friendId' from people;
+---------------------------------+
| value->'$.friends[*].friendId' |
+---------------------------------+
| NULL                            |
| ["123", "foo"]                  |
+---------------------------------+
```

So how come the query `select * from people where value->'$.friends[*].friendId' = "123";` returns no results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JSON_CONTAINS` with the JSON array value I'm interested in works:

```
select * from people where JSON_CONTAINS (value, {"friends": [{"friendId": "123"}]});
```

Comment: This also works if objects in `friends` array have more fields. All specified values must match for the row to be returned. So it's like an `AND` operator. For example if objects in `friends` array have one more field `name` then the above query will still return the same result. And if you specify `JSON_CONTAINS (value, {"friends": [{"friendId": "123", "name": "Andrew"}]})` then only rows that have `friendId=123` AND `name=Andrew` will be returned.